# How We can parse .xqy File in sonar?

Tags: parsing, plugins, sonarqube, xquery, naming-conventions

Is There any sonar xquery plugin which can parse and check the naming convention of xquery files.
What types of files we need to create for xquery plugin?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the conventions that you are looking to enforce? Do you mean naming conventions for methods and variables, filenames, or what? There is a Sonar XQuery Plugin  https://github.com/malteseduck/sonar-xquery-plugin

Comment: @ Mads Hansen yeah, there is sonar XQuery plugin available.but do you know how to check naming convention of XQuery files and also file size in sonar? convention like file name starting with xq_, and we want to check this naming convention from the directory itself.